# jQuery Code Doesn't Work on Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax code that works perfectly. But I need it to change the class of the button that fires the jQuery ajax event when clicked when successful. But my code on `sucess:` doesn't work. Please see code below.

**jQuery Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm').click(function() {
            var pollQId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/LikePoll",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'pollQId': pollQId }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function() {
                    $(this).addClass("btn btn-primary btn-sm");
                },

                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Please help me. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` in the success callback is not the `this` you expect, to make this param consistent to the clicked button, pass `context: this` as additional param to your `.ajax` function.

You can find more info from [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> context
>
> - Type: PlainObject
> - This object will be the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By    default, the context is an object that represents the Ajax settings
>     used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>     $.ajax).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm').click(function() {
            var pollQId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/LikePoll",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'pollQId': pollQId }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",

                // Add this param, so the `this` in the success callback
                // will be the clicked button.
                context: this,

                success: function() {
                    $(this).addClass("btn btn-primary btn-sm");
                },

                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: You are the greatest! Thanks so much.